# Can I start a FaceTime by myself without other participants (similar to Facebook Messenger's room feature)?

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

Strange question I know but I need to view myself on the FaceTime video screen for a project but don't have any contacts that use an iPhone. On Facebook Messenger you can start a video call (or room) by yourself and create a link to invite other participants. Is this possible somehow on FaceTime? If it is, is it possible with all iOS versions or only recent versions?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Don't you automatically see yourself on the screen as soon as you start Facetime?

Comment: You can start one, but you can't answer it, unless you have another device you can answer it on. Before the session starts you can see yourself; as soon as you try to connect it just shows the 'me' icon until answered. I tested with iPhone & answered on my Mac. Then it works. If you have a Mac, though, you don't need this hoop-jumping, because FaceTime launches with a view of yourself.